# pandas select rows with the max value of some columns for each different value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas like this:

```
    id  some_type   some_date   some_data
0   1   A           19/12/1995  X
1   2   A           10/04/1997  Y
2   2   B           05/03/2013  Z
3   2   B           09/05/2017  W
4   2   B           09/05/2017  R
5   3   A           01/07/1998  M
6   3   B           09/08/2009  N
```

I need for each value of id, the rows that have the max value of some_type and some_date without deleting any value of some_data.

In other words, what I need is the following:

```
    id  some_type   some_date   some_data
0   1   A           19/12/1995  X
3   2   B           09/05/2017  W
4   2   B           09/05/2017  R
6   3   B           09/08/2009  N
```

Comment: Why don't you have `id` 1 in your output? and repeated ids if the task is for each different value of `id`?

Comment: sorry my mistake, I will fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with `sort_values`, `groupby` and `apply` by keeping the rows with the last value some_type and some_date:

```
df_output = (df.sort_values(by=['some_type','some_date']).groupby('id')
                .apply(lambda df_g: df_g[(df_g['some_type'] == df_g['some_type'].iloc[-1]) & 
                                          (df_g['some_date'] == df_g['some_date'].iloc[-1])])
                  .reset_index(0,drop=True))
```

and the output is:

```
   id some_type  some_date some_data
0   1         A 1995-12-19         X
3   2         B 2017-09-05         W
4   2         B 2017-09-05         R
6   3         B 2009-09-08         N
```

EDIT: if you don't care about the indexes, you can also use `merge`:

```
#first get the last one once sorting
df_last = df.sort_values(['some_type','some_date']).groupby('id')['some_type','some_date'].last()
# now merge with inner to keep the one you want
df_output  = df.merge(df_last ,how='inner')
```

you will get the same result besides indexes

Comment: maybe a `drop_duplicates(['id`],keep='last')` after the sorted value will be a nice alternative option?

Comment: @LucasDresl but if you do `drop_duplicates(['id'],keep='last')` you will ends up with one row for each id. Of what I understand of the quetion, the OP wants to keep two rows for id=2 as they have the same value in some_type and some_date :)

Comment: Oh! I just saw the both max values are the same for id=2, that makes my solution of using `head(1)` broken.

Comment: @akilat90 I think it why the question is not a duplicate, and it is what I understood, maybe I'm wrong

Comment: No, you're correct. My one won't work when there are multiple max values - I removed it.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because the first approach gives me what I expected in my real life problem. The other approaches give me the next error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.

Answer (score 2):

Create a mask with `groupby`  and `max()` and apply. But first convert to datetime:

```
df['some_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['some_date'])
m = df.groupby('id')['some_type','some_date'].transform(lambda x: x == x.max()).all(1)  
df = df[m]
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

text = '''\
id  some_type   some_date   some_data
1   A           19/12/1995  X
2   A           10/04/1997  Y
2   B           05/03/2013  Z
2   B           09/05/2017  W
2   B           09/05/2017  R
3   A           01/07/1998  M
3   B           09/08/2009  N'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(text)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+')

df['some_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['some_date'])

m = df.groupby('id')['some_type','some_date'].transform(lambda x: x == x.max()).all(1)

df = df[m]

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   id some_type  some_date some_data
0   1         A 1995-12-19         X
3   2         B 2017-09-05         W
4   2         B 2017-09-05         R
6   3         B 2009-09-08         N
```

Comment: Off topic: in case if you're not aware: you can use `pd.read_clipboard()` to copy dataframes in questions

Comment: @akilat90 I know (thanks) and it is great. However prefer this as it creates a code you can easy copy and verify.